# Facebook Like Button - can´t build archive with the new feature FBLikeControl

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, ios7, facebook-like

I want to integrate Facebook like Button with the new feature FBLikeControl. On the facebook page they have written it is only for developement and not for publication on the AppStore.

Here is the Tutorial from facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button/

When I want to build an archive with my code I get the error message "Use of undeclared identifier FBBetaFeaturesLikeButton".

Is there a way to solve this problem or if there's any other alternative solution, I would appreciate that.

Here is my code:

```
[FBSettings enableBetaFeature:FBBetaFeaturesLikeButton];
[FBSettings enablePlatformCompatibility:NO];

FBLikeControl *like = [[FBLikeControl alloc] init];
like.frame = CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width-like.frame.size.width)/2, facebookY, 60, 20);
like.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/pages/abcdefgh/123456789?ref=tn_tnmn";
[self addSubview: like];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button/) says:

   > FBLikeControl is a preview feature and may not be deployed to the App
   >   Store. Only developers and testers of your Facebook app will be able
   >   to use the Like Button.

   is the reason you are unable to built the archive.
2. There are several ways to implement like, the one which worked for me is as follows:

   ```
   [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/object-id_to_like/likes" 
                            parameters:nil
                            HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
   // Handle error here
   }];
   ```

   [Here is the Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/object/likes)

**EDIT:** It is pretty simple, you just have to replace FBLikeControl code in your project with the above method call replacing `object-id_to_like` to the actual post-id/ object-id. What the method does is it POSTS a like on corresponding object/post.

In case you have problem to fetch the object id of the object/post you can fetch it using same method with the HTTPMethod parameter set to @"GET". Following code will return posts from your timeline:

```
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/home"// you can change this to @"/me/feed" if required
                                 parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error ) {
                          if (!error){
                              // Fetch Post-id/Object-id here
                          }else{
                              // handle error here
                          }
                      }];
```

Comment: I think you are right and it is not possible to publish it to the AppStore with this version!! Its a pity because this is a very good way. Do you have a tutorial or a sample code with your version to add a facebook like button. On your link is only a very short description and i cant build it. It would be great if you can tell me!!!

Comment: I tried your code but i have a problem. The code dont show a like button on the screen. I´m sorry but i´m not so familiar with facebook! I think i need an object with a frame and an image who shows the like button, or not? I would be great if you can help me again! its the first time for me do something with facebook. I want to get a facebook like button who likes a facebook page. Thanks

Comment: Yes, thats true. The code won't show like button. It will just post a like. Putting up the UI is what you have to do. That can be done using a UIButton or any thing you prefer. So you have to do is Add a `UIButton`(I'll call it LikeButton) and post the **like** in LikeButton's action method.